# StreamingResponseBody returning empty body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple `Spring Boot` controller that serves zip-files, which can get fairly large. So in order to not having to load the entire file content into memory I'm creating an `InputStream` from the file to be read and return a `StreamingResponseBody` like this:

```
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/export")
public class ExportController {
        
    @GetMapping(value = "/{fileUuid}")
    public StreamingResponseBody exportFile(@PathVariable String fileUuid, HttpServletResponse response) {    
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"export.zip\"");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(this.resolveFile(fileUuid));
        return outputStream -> {
            StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);  // also tried inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);              
        };
    }

    public File resolveFile(String fileUuid) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, this works fine for the very first request - but after that around **80% of** requests are returned with an empty response body (the http-response just contains response headers). We're using `JDK11` and `Spring Boot 2.4.3`.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

EDIT:

Strangely enough, I was able to solve the issue by wrapping the `FileInputStream` in a `InputStreamResource` and returning this resource instead of a `StreamingResponseBody`:

```
// ...
var resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(this.resolveFile(fileUuid)));
return resource;
```

But I'm still curious of what's wrong with the original approach..

Comment: Doesn’t really explain why it works and then doesn’t, but did you try moving the InputStream entirely inside the lambda? Also, do you close/flush both Input and OutputStream? With Java11 I don’t see a reason to still use `StreamUtils.copy` anymore, since there is `InputStream.transferTo`

Comment: Yep, tried fiddling around with closing/flushing the streams explicitly but no avail. `transferTo`  does not seem to solve the issue either. But..I was able to solve the problem, see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a similar problem and it turns out you might have a synchronous stream copy in filter happening before the asynchronous call filling the response outputStream. Check if disabling other servlet filters makes it work. also additional logging will help in revealing the issue (check response data size, see whether it grows at some point in the filter chain).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this makes sense. Will investigate it further.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That was exactly the issue I faced, I didn't spot a filter that copied some data to response, effectively disabling anything that was added to that response later in the controllers method

Comment: THANK YOU @francesco-berti!! I've spend days investigating why a StreamingResponseBody was not streaming the download file or returning an empty file and finally found out that there was a filter messing with the outputStream. Removing such filter makes everything work nice.